# Inserting lots of mysql rows that have wrongly formatted dates

Tags: mysql, date, insert, formatting

I am trying to insert a lot of rows into my MySQL database with date formats that aren't what MySQL is expecting. I am inserting a lot of rows that look similar to this:

```
insert into tableName values ('firstName', 'lastName', 'address', '01-JAN-93');
```

I have a lot of rows that are formatted with the date incorrectly. As I understand it, MySQL expects '1993-01-01'.

Is there any way that I can easily achieve this? I was thinking about using STR_TO_DATE around all my inserts, but I am trying to investigate easier ways than modifying all the insert statements. I am not able to modify the data that's coming in.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Use `str_to_date()` to create the date in the right format.  That doesn't seem very hard.  Or, insert everything into a staging table in the database, and do the conversion once when loading the actual table.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. For str_to_date() I'm trying

STR_TO_DATE('01-JAN-93', '%Y-%m-%d')

I'm getting an Incorrect datetime value '01-JAN-93' for function str_to_date.

Comment: Got it to work! :) 

Formatted STR_TO_DATE('01-JAN-93', '%d-%b-%y')

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) it will convert the string to a standard SQL format date
It should be fairly easy to do

```
INSERT INTO tableName VALUES('firstName', 'lastName', 'address', str_to_date('01-JAN-93', '%d-%b-%y'));
```